# React Native modules into an existing app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I've been working on adding react native to an existing app. I followed the guide on the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) and after fixing some errors that popped up all was well.

Now I want to use react native components to talk to native code. There are a few use-cases that I need but the current one is that I have an AndroidToolbar and when clicking the navIcon I want to end the current Activity (I want to use native navigation). My thought was to create a native module and just simply call it from my react native code (natively calling onBackPressed). The problem is that when following [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) they suggest to add the package to getPackages function within your ReactApplication. Something like:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    ...

    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage(),
                new AnExampleReactPackage());
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem is that if you follow the "Integration with existing apps" docs then you never create a ReactApplication. Instead you just create an Activity somewhere in your app and just start that activity somewhere in your app. If anyone can point me in the right direction for how to call native code when you have integrated into an existing app, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having a related problem.